# How to parallelize for loop pandas for changing data types and calling other functions

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

It's quite a common problem to change the data types of certain columns in a pandas dataframe. Without completely re-writing all of my code to be compatible with dask I would like to parallelize a few for loops in my code.

For example I want to change the data types of specific columns, and since there are 700+ columns that need to be changed it could be quite slow. I have seen many questions about parallelizing functions using `multiprocessing` but I haven't seen any solutions that seems to speed up my code.

```
cont_vars = [...] # list of continuous variables
cat_vars = [...] # list of categorical variables

for col in cont_vars:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('float32')

for col in cat_vars:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category').cat.as_ordered()
```

I am also having a hard time parallelizing a loop that calls a function. For example:

```
for col in df[i for i in df.columns if i.startswith('Funnel')]:
    df = function1(df, col, 9, 1)

for col in [i for i in df.columns if i.endswith('Bracket')]:
    df = pd.merge_asof(df, function2(df[col], 19), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I strongly suspect that this would be a bad move using multiprocessing. I would imagine the dataframe will be completely copied in memory to all processes unless you use some kind of manager, and then have to knit it all back together again at the end.

Comment: Oohhh i see... So it would take up a lot of memory... How would you go about solving this issue? It takes about 20 minutes to run this code and it's all single threaded.

Comment: Not just memory inefficient but the time is likely to increase, not just by massive copies but either IPC or pulling the result back together at the end. I have no ideas off the top of my head, I'll  have a think how you might push the data conversion under the GIL.

Comment: What is actually taking the time here? I suspect the majority is tied up in the functions, rather than changing datatype? Have you looked at vectorizing those calculations? Mapping functions will run in Python time

Comment: Multiprocessing also can be dangerous for a shared database, as it is best practice to wait for one entire process to finish before implementing the next change or process as the objects are not shared in memory. Instead they are recombined at the end, so if you have multiprocesses on a df, the first would need to execute before the second if operating on the same df.

Comment: How is your data sourced? Many [pandas i/o tools](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) allow you to set types upon import. If data frame is built in other ways, show us as there are many ways to cast values into Series or DataFrames.

Comment: I only want to parallelize the loops that do not require the first loop to be executed first. The first for loop on function2 does not require function1 to be calculated in order for function2 to work. Since that is the case I feel there is a good way to solve this problem.